# Refresh div after delete table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can successfully delete rows of my table and remove it from the table with jquery and ajax. On top of my table i have the number of rows displayed. How can i refresh the **div (update_count)** to show the decremented number after deleting ?

```
<div id="update_count"><?=$num_count?> data</i></div> 
<table  class="table">
 <tr>
  <th style="width:1px"><strong>Date</strong></th>
    <th style="width:5px">Labo</th>
     <th style="width:5px">Delete</th>
      <tr>
      <?php foreach($IndicacionesLab as $row)

     {
      ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?=$row->insert_time;?></td>
    <td><?=$row->laboratory;?></td>
     <td> <a title="Eliminar laboratorio <?=$row->laboratory;?>" class="st deletelab" id="<?=$row->id_lab; ?>"  style="background:rgb(223,0,0);cursor:pointer">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
   <?php
     }
     ?>
   </table>
```

Js

```
 $(".deletelab").click(function(){
  if (confirm("Sure to delete ?"))
        { 
      var el = this;
       var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=base_url('admin/DeleteHistLab')?>',
        data: {id : del_id},
        success:function(response) {
    // Removing row from HTML Table
      $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
      $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
       $(this).remove();
            });
          }
       });
      }
     })
```

Comment: Why don't you just reduce the number?

Comment: I would like to reduce it in staying in the same page. Just show how i could do that that's why i post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity keep all the data rows in a `<tbody>`

```
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
         <th> heading 1 </th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>     
     <tr>
         <th> data 1 </th>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then after you remove the row get the `length` of all rows remaining

```
$('#update_count').text( $('#my-table tbody tr').length + ' Items')
```

Comment: thanks you for your response, but i don't see where you use : Items.

Comment: Just some text that would read like "8 Items" ... if all you want is a number remove that part

Comment: I tried it it's not working, it makes my delete function stop working..

Comment: it's not showing error but the function stops working as it was.

Comment: Note that `this` inside the `success` is not the element. Should change that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159944/discussion-between-diasline-and-charlietfl).